# What is the current use of Plural vs. Singular second person when addressing to parents?

Tags: число, займенники, пошанна-множина

In many classic books, I see addressing parents by **plural of nobility** (Ukr: *Пошанна множина*), most probably as a sign of respect and dignity:

> — ***Ви***, тату, говорите до мене, наче до маленької, – сказала Марта, осміхнувшись.
>   (Іван Нечуй-Левицький, «Хмари»)

What is the current, **actual** amount of usage for this construct in modern Ukrainian?

---

Further reading:

- [Pluralis majestatis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralis_majestatis)
- [Вживання особових займенників](http://labook.com.ua/book_stilistika-dilovo-movi_672/29_-26.-vzhivannya-osobovih-zajmennikv)

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko same here. I've found a couple of forums with people discussing this matter:
[golos sokalshchyny](http://golossokal.com.ua/cikavo/kak-obrashhatsya-roditelyam-ty-ili-vy.html),
[maidan](http://maidan.org.ua/arch/mova/1109751486.html). Therefore, we can't say "it isn't used at all". People there share their experience of using both approaches.

Comment: Серед видачі гугла на цю тему багато публічно доступних робіт посилається на  [Історія українського мовного етикету. Звертання](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/publications/books/catalog/2006/Pages/845.aspx).
 також
[тут](http://old.philology.lnu.edu.ua/visnyk/56_1_2012/2012_56(1)_Strilec.pdf) з посиланням на роботу Миронюк говориться про те що подібне шанобливе звертання до батьків має тенденцію зменшуватися через "зміну відносин з опікунських на партнерські", але поточний стан справ не цитується

Comment: @Chizh I propose to convert that into an answer.

Comment: as for exact numbers I have [this](http://zbruc.eu/node/41931) but it's definitely offtopic :)

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, you're wrong. I recently saw a la-a-arge topic on Facebook. Most (10:1 or even 100:1) uses "ти". Still, supporters of "Ви" **were definitely present** (those who call their own parents in this way and/or teach their children to refer them in this way). There were even combinations (like call "ти" when child is small and re-teach for "Ви" when child becomes teenager). (I also thought that "Ви" isn't used for parents nowadays, but...)

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2635

Answer (score 7):

My mother always said `Ви` as a plural to her parents, grandparents, aunts and uncles. My father always used `ти` as a singular to his parents, grandparents, aunts and uncles.

I am not that young anymore and I use singular form for my parents and grandparents but plural for aunts and uncles. Generation of my parents, according to my observation, used `Ви` in 70-80% of cases. My generation - 10-20%. I am originally from south west of Ukraine.

So in general I would say it depends on the region, religion and real amount of respect you want to put in your words. A couple of words about religion: what I have seen is - the more religious people the more common is to use plural form.

I would also agree with Chizh's comment - the tendency I see is to use more and more singular form.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Ukrainian addressing parents by plural of nobility is very rare. Google search for "мамо, **ви**" returns only 4660 resylts, while more common version "мамо, **ти**" returns 200 000 results.

To my experience, plural of nobility nowadays is used mostly when addressing mother-in-law by word "мамо".

Comment: Your research would be great if it contained other combinations like *«ви, мамо»*, *«ви, люба мамо»*, *«матусю, ви»*, *«ви, маманю»* etc. Admittedly, I can't build such search query; but if you can, that would be a great answer.

Comment: I agree, you should extend your answer with other search results.