# „Батько“ з дїєсловом множини чи як множина

Tags: число, пошанна-множина

Конструкцїя: [*батько*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE) *дїєслово множини*.

Чим зумовлено? Наскільки менї відомо, наразі є множина *батьки*, а до *батько* крипіться *дїєслово однини*. Чи це якась норма?

---

Зустрів у перекладї [„Пісня льоду та вогню“](http://ice-and-fire.in.ua/page/got/) від Вячислава Бродового [[fb]](https://www.facebook.com/vyacheslav.brodovoy).

> — Тримай-но конячку  як слїд, — прошепотїв  він. — І не  смій відвертатися, бо **батько знатимуть**.

На помилку не схоже, бо трапляється не рідко, наведу лише деякі:

> *1.* — Королева теж сердита, — стиха відповів Джон дядькові. — Удень  **батько повели** короля до крипти, а королева не хотїла, щоб він ішов.
>
> *2.* — Візьміть мене з собою, як  поїдете на  Стїну, — у раптовому  пориваннї попрохав Джон. — **Батько дозволять**, якщо ви попросите, неодмінно дозволять!
>
> *3.* — **Батько послали** мене виховуватися у Соколиному Гнїздї, коли мені  було вісїм, —  відказав Нед. — Пан  Родрік каже, що принц Джофрі та Робб незлюбили один одного.
>
> *4.*— Вона не собака, а лютововк,  — заперечила Санса, поки Панночка облизувала їй пальцї шорстким язиком.  — А ще **батько сказали**, що ми  можемо тримати їх при собі, якщо хочемо.

Схоже, що таке тільки в дїяльоґах. Про стиль перекладу пан Бродовий [згадує:](http://ice-and-fire.in.ua/page/about/)

> Ключова моя ідея полягала в тому, щоб адаптувати мову перекладу з використанням українських старожитностей, надати їй виразного східноєвропейського колориту, де б у титулах, звертаннях, побутових назвах, військових термінах, у двірському пишномовʼї та посполитих теревенях чулося відлуння старої Русї-України, Литви, Речі Посполитої, козацтва, а подеколи й різноманітних наших сусїдів: чехів, угорцїв, татар, москвинів тощо.

Подїбну конструкцїю знаходжу в инших текстах (теж лише деякі).

> [*1.*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=WDs4b875vDUC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=%22%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&source=bl&ots=WvdvyXBE2u&sig=6go3b8XGgI9uFrQwsclPv7vw4ek&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7gOSB6YnWAhUiQJoKHRH3DKoQ6AEIQTAE#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&f=false) Таких кораблем заїхали до Ґімлї і **мої батьки** … *Мої покійнї* **батько**, тодї ще *самотнї*, *були* *провідником* цього транспорту, за яким їхали зі своїми родичами і **мої мама**, тодї ще молода дївчина … **Мої батько були** будївничим майстром ще в Копичинцях, а цей фах вони перебрали від від свого батька.
>
> [*2.*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=sigSAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&dq=%22%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl9cLG6YnWAhXFCpoKHTrmAHAQ6AEIyAIwKw) **Батько були** иншої думки … Не памʼятаю, щоб **батько були** *пригнїченими* чи навіть *похмурі*, хоч життя було не з легких.
>
> [*3.*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=DY8jAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&dq=%22%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl9cLG6YnWAhXFCpoKHTrmAHAQ6AEIwQIwKg) Покійний мій **батько були пообіцяли** кількасот карбованцїв.

Тут також *прикметник в множинї*, схожа ситуацїя з *мама*. Це відноситься тїльки до родичів?

---

Споріднене

1. [What is the current use of Plural vs. Singular second person when addressing to parents?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/243/)

   - [Royal we](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we)
   - [Детермінацїя способів апеляцїї в українській і польскій мовах](http://old.philology.lnu.edu.ua/visnyk/56_1_2012/2012_56(1)_Strilec.pdf) (Інна Стрілець)
   - [Займенники „ТИ“–„ВИ“ в манїпулятивнїй стратегії позитиву](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/71373/50-Shkicka.pdf) ([Ірина Шкіцька](http://www.tneu.edu.ua/faculty/uf/kafedra-didu-uf/staff-didu-uf/7307-shkicka-iryna-yuriivna.html))

Comment: Чому Ви замість літери **і** вживаєте **ї**?

Comment: @user2513149 ось прошу ознайомитися з  [цією](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/60/92) відповіддю на [Навіщо потрібен апостроф перед «ї»?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/53/92) i пов'язане з ним [Походження літери Ї в українській абетці](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/256/92)

звісно у наведених прикладах не давньоукраїнська мова, але,нмд, перекладач намагається такою синтетичною архаїчністю передати особливості оригінального тексту

Comment: @chizh, тільки в цьому разі не перекладач, а автор запитання. Stegetsj, по-моєму, було б добре в цитатах лишити оригінальний правопис (чи принаймні стандартний не змінювати на нестандартний; хоча я навіть нестандартний на стандартний в цитатах не змінюю).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я ʼради прикола рїшив поглянути на слово *вони* і натрапив:

> <sup>[Словник української мови у 20 томах](//sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=15846&page=525)</sup>
>
> 2. *розм.* Уживається для вираження пошани до однієї особи будь-якої статі.
>
>    > *Довгий і блідий швейцар ‥ прошепотів: Вони ще не встали… “Вони” — то був редактор* (М. Коцюбинський); *— Ех, Тимку, не знаєш ти дядька Мусія: вони в нас хитрі!* (А. Головко); *— Це кричали вони! — сказав він, роблячи наголос на “вони”, і махнув рукою в Майїн бік* (М. Хвильовий).

Тобто задля *вираження пошани* і не лише до родичів.

Ось тут про воникання в освітнїй книзї «[Українська фраза](//r2u.org.ua/node/186)» (1928) Миколи Сулими: подана ґраматіка і геть троʼ гісторії.

> [§ 7. ЗНАЧІННЯ Й УЖИВАННЯ МНОЖИНИ](//r2u.org.ua/node/195)
>
> Опріч випадків, коли однина набирає множинного значіння, буває в мові й таке, що множина заступає однину, ц.т. формами множини говорять про одну особу, річ чи явище.
>
> 3. В українській народній мові частенько ще трапляється така множина (замість однини), що нею виявляють чемність, пошану до якоїсь особи. Це — пошанна множина. Хоч вона прийшла до нас із Західньої Европи пізніше, ніж маєстатна й авторська, та тимчасом вона дуже швидко поширилася скрізь і добре прищепилася в народі. Тому то пошанна множина й справляє вражіння притаманної риси в народніх говірках.
>
>    Виявляється ця множина от чим:
>
>    2. У заочних розмовах про тих самих людей говорять *вони* плюс третя особа множини замість *він* чи *вона* плюс третя особа однини дієслова; напр.: *Бідний дядько Панас! **Вони** за всіма **оступаються**, а всі проти **них**!* (І. Тобілевич). *Дядько Лев **казали**, що тут мені дадуть ґрунтець і хату, бо в-осени **хотять** мене женити* (Л. Українка). *Батько **сердиті**… **стоять**, часник **чистять*** (А. Тесленко). *В похилих літах **були дід*** (В. Чапля). *Завтра **прийдуть** до нас пані,  **казали**, що принесуть ліки нашій Настуньці* (М. Черемшина).
>
>    В обох випадках і всі прикметникові слова, що стосуються до тих *ви* й *вони*, звичайно так само мають вигляд множини. ***Ви такі веселі були** вчора. **Вони такі добрі**, що кожному **допомагають*** і т. інш.
>
>    Заочну пошанну множину не завжди доводиться наслідувати; в широкій літературній обіхідці, в офіціяльних паперах і т. інш. вона просто недоречна.

Троʼ про [гісторію воникання](https://localhistory.org.ua/texts/chitanka/nekhai-pannuntsia-ne-gnivaiutsia-iak-zvertalisia-odne-do-odnogo-ukrayintsi-100-rokiv-tomu/) від [Василя Сїмовича](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).

> Таксамо німці. Ще в XVI. в. вони «викали» (ihrzen) один одному. Тепер цю функцію перебрала 3. ос. множ., при чому ніхто, що говорить німецькою мовою, й не догадується, що нім. *Sie* це ввічливий спосіб звертатися до розмовника в 3. ос. множ., замість 2. ос. Цей спосіб перебрали були колись від німців чехи, і ще на початку XIX. ст. чути було часто «онікання» (звертатися формою 3. ос. мн. «оні»). Проти такої форми виступала свідома чеська інтеліґенція, пропаґуючи скрізь «славянське ви» – і тепер «онікають» іще тільки селяни в розмові з панами, а той міщани, звертаючись до селян або старших людей узагалі…
>
> Росіяни, чехи, серби, болгари – спинилися на «виканні». Українська ж інтеліґенція, здається під польським впливом, старається зазначувати ввічливість тим, що вживає 3. ос., але – множини (це вже українське). Це щось наче контамінація, як ми такі явища звемо в лінґвістиці (мама були, нехай тато скажуть, як пан професор собі бажають)… У селян такі вислови теж часті (що єґомость кажуть, нехай пані зажадають, панич мені дали, нехай панночка, чи паннунця не гніваються). Розуміється, що такі вислови товариської мови відомі тільки тут, на західних землях (на Волині зрідка), а що нема їх на сході, то можна зробити висновок, що це також вплив польської товариської мови.

Answer (score 2):

Це звичайна повага, в даному випадку до батьків. Але також існує в багатьох різних формах як ввічливість. "Підскажіть, котра година?", - звернення до однієї людини, але дієслово вжите у формі множини. "Чи не підказали б Ви, котра година?", - зміст подібний, але тепер у формі множини займенник. Звертання до батьків "на Ви" колись було вельми поширеним, зараз же збереглося головно в Карпатському регіоні.

Comment: -1: це не «повага», а цілком собі лінгвістичний термін **пошанна множина**, яка існує у купі мов, включно з древнім санскритом і сучасною тайською чи філіппіно. Хороша, якісна відповідь на це запитання повинна ґрунтуватися на джерелах, а не на субʼєктивних здогадках дописувача.

Comment: А чим пошана відрізняється від поваги?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, тим, що «повага» — це соціологічний термін, а «пошанна множина» — лінгвістичний. Приблизно так само, як «пряма лінія» відрізняється від «прямого кута».